# Counting words in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, counting

i'm doing a work with a table that i made on ORACLE (sql) and one exercice asks me to count how many time several words are repeated.
Does anyone know what commands I have to use?
Thanks!

Uptadete: Well, what I have are movies with an associated movie studio (in the same table these two data) and what I have to do is indicate how many movies each studio has, so I need a command to count each studio name. Is this possible?

Comment: Give us some example = start data and expected result from that data. Also, please do comment your and give some feedback to your previous question. When you ask help it is nice to say thank you or something else to others when they help you...

Comment: Several words? Which words? Do you have a list of words? Please share the sample data and expected output.

Comment: Well, what I have are movies with an associated movie studio (in the same table these two data) and what I have to do is indicate how many movies each studio has, so I need a command to count each studio name. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I feel you can try a combination of `count` and `group by` clause.

For Eg :

```
SELECT COUNT(STUDIO) "No. of Movies Running",STUDIO
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY STUDIO;
```

This must do the magic for you !!!

Comment: Thank you so much!!